# undefined is not a function

Tags: javascript, rightjs

So I'm trying to use rightjs's autocompleter (http://rightjs.org/ui/autocompleter) but when loading it up in my web browser I'm getting 'uncaught TypeError: undefined is not a function' on line 112. any ideas? my code: http://paste.pocoo.org/show/409248/

Comment: I posted a link to the source..

Comment: code is better than link

Comment: Actually I was talking about your html and script code where you're loading the right.js and the autocomplete and where you're trying to use it.

Comment: http://paste.pocoo.org/show/409248/

Comment: where is it actually giving you the exception? what file and line of code? -- line 112 does not give us much idea and it could be in any of the js files before...

Comment: Line 112 is in one of your JS files, you'll have to post more code/links

Answer (score 2):

My guess is you don't have right.js included before right-autocompleter.js because it is complaining that RightJS.Class is not a function which it is true if Class is not defined in the RightJS object.

Comment: right.js is above right-autocompleter.js in the html file

Comment: could it not be loading it 'in time' or something?

Comment: Try checking if it being loaded at all. If you are using IE8 or IE9 try F12. For Firefox try firebug with F12 as well. In Chrome try Ctrl+Shift+J. Verify that right.js was loaded. If you reload the page you should check for errors in the console. If right was loaded one of the other js files might be interfering with it somehow.